# magento - error on checkout page

Tags: magento, translation

I am in the middle of translating a english shop to French for a client. 
However, something appears to have broken. 
On the checkout page, when I click the continue button to allow for first time registration, nothing happens.

Even stranger, on the actual page I can see the following code appearing underneath the button:

```
yCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) { loginForm.submit(); } }
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a missing quote or malformed HTML or PHP tag. Check the HTML preceding the code that gets printed out.

There's nothing that really jumps out. One little thing:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loginForm.submit()">
```

should be

```
<a href="#" onclick="loginForm.submit(); return false;">
```

Also if there's a javascript error and / or the `loginForm` variable doesn't get created properly then the form won't submit - be sure to check your Javascript console.

Comment: Thanks Greg.. that removed the mysterious line of code from the page.

However the button still doesn't do anything. Any ideas?
Regards,
Fiona

Comment: Hi Greg,

I think I know why its not working! the Billing tab has disappeared. Any ideas why? I did copy over the site from an existing one, and everything else looks ok to me. Where are the tabs pulled from?

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 0):

The site is in dev so sadly cannot provide URL.

Here is some of the source code (hopefully the relevant part)... not sure if its any use to you:

```
<ol id="checkoutSteps" class="one-page-checkout">
<li id="opc-login" class="section allow ">
    <div class="head">
        <h3><span class="step-count">1</span> &nbsp;Processus de commande</h3><a href="#">Edit</a>
    </div>
    <div id="checkout-step-login" class="box a-item" style="display:none;">
        <div class="col2-set">
<div class="col-1">
    <h4>S’enregistrer et Ouvrir un Compte Client</h4>

                <strong>Enregistrez-vous et gagner du temps !</strong><br/>
        En créant votre compte sur notre site, vous pourrez faire vos achats plus rapidement, garder votre panier d'une visite à l'autre et suivre vos commandes. Lifes2Good s'engage à sécuriser vos informations et à les garder strictement confidentielles.            <ul class="disc">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
                        <input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register" checked="checked" />
        </div>
<div class="col-2">
    <h4>Se connecter</h4>
            <form id="login-form" action="http://www.viviscal.fr/index.php/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post">
        <p><strong>Already registered?</strong><br/>
        Please log in below:</p>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <label for="login-email">Email Address <span class="required">*</span></label><br/>
                    <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="login-email" name="login[username]" value=""/>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <label for="login-password">Mot de Passe <span class="required">*</span></label><br/>
                    <input type="password" class="input-text required-entry" id="login-password" name="login[password]" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col2-set">
<div class="col-1">
    <div class="button-set">
        <p class="required">&nbsp;</p>
        <a href="#" onclick="checkout.setMethod()"><img src="http://www.viviscal.fr/skin/frontend/default/helloclean/images/btn_continue.gif" alt="Continue" class="v-middle"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-2">
    <div class="button-set">
        <p class="required">* Champs obligatoires</p>
        <a href="http://www.viviscal.fr/index.php/customer/account/forgotpassword/" class="f-left">Vous avez oublié votre mot de passe ? </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="loginForm.submit()"><img src="http://www.viviscal.fr/skin/frontend/default/helloclean/images/btn_login.gif" alt="Se connecter" class="v-middle"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
$('login-email').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
$('login-password').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
function bindLoginPost(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
        loginForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Regards,
Fiona